# Memory Leaks with OpenMP Tasks and the Intel Compiler Suite

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, openmp, intel, intel-fortran

I am trying to parallelize an algorithm using DAG-Scheduling via OpenMP tasks and there many programs are killed by the Linux kernel due to Out-Of-Memory after a calls to the parallelized code although the allocated memory is only 1% of the servers main memory. But this happens only if I use the Intel Compilers from 2015, 2016 or even the new 2017 edition.

Here is a small example building the same task dependency graph as the algorithm crashing:

```
PROGRAM OMP_TASK_PROBLEM
    IMPLICIT NONE 

    INTEGER M, N 
    PARAMETER(M = 256, N=256) 
    DOUBLE PRECISION X(M,N) 

    X(1:M,1:N) = 0.0D0

    CALL COMPUTE_X(M, N, X, M) 

    ! WRITE(*,*) X (1:M, 1:N) 

END PROGRAM 


SUBROUTINE COMPUTE_X(M,N, X, LDX) 
    IMPLICIT NONE 
    INTEGER M, N, LDX 
    DOUBLE PRECISION X(LDX, N) 
    INTEGER K, L, KOLD, LOLD


    !$omp parallel default(shared) 
    !$omp master
    L = 1 
    DO WHILE ( L .LE. N ) 
        K = M 
        DO WHILE (K .GT. 0)
            IF ( K .EQ. M .AND. L .EQ. 1) THEN 
                !$omp  task depend(out:X(K,L)) firstprivate(K,L) default(shared)  
                X(K,L) = 0 
                !$omp end task 
            ELSE IF ( K .EQ. M .AND. L .GT. 1) THEN 
                !$omp  task depend(out:X(K,L)) depend(in:X(K,LOLD)) firstprivate(K,L,LOLD) default(shared)  
                X(K,L) = 1 + X(K,LOLD)
                !$omp end task 
            ELSE IF ( K .LT. M .AND. L .EQ. 1) THEN 
                !$omp  task depend(out:X(K,L)) depend(in:X(KOLD,L)) firstprivate(K,L,KOLD) default(shared)   
                X(K,L) = 2 + X(KOLD,L) 
                !$omp end task 
            ELSE
                !$omp  task depend(out:X(K,L)) depend(in:X(KOLD,L),X(K,LOLD)) firstprivate(K,L,KOLD, LOLD) default(shared) 
                X(K,L) = X(KOLD, L) + X(K,LOLD)
                !$omp end task 
            END IF 

            KOLD = K
            K = K - 1
        END DO

        LOLD = L
        L = L + 1
    END DO
    !$omp end master 
    !$omp taskwait 
    !$omp end parallel 
END SUBROUTINE
```

After compiling it using `ifort -qopenmp -g omp_test.f90` and running it via `valgrind` it reports:

```
==21071== LEAK SUMMARY:
==21071==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21071==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21071==      possibly lost: 118,489,088 bytes in 113 blocks
==21071==    still reachable: 1,286 bytes in 35 blocks
==21071==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

where the `--leak-check=full` option shows the following details:

```
==21071== 1,048,576 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 22 of 26
==21071==    at 0x4C29BFD: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21071==    by 0x516A807: bget(kmp_info*, long) (kmp_alloc.c:741)
==21071==    by 0x516A52D: ___kmp_fast_allocate (kmp_alloc.c:2012)
==21071==    by 0x51CD917: __kmp_task_alloc (kmp_tasking.c:991)
==21071==    by 0x51CD886: __kmpc_omp_task_alloc (kmp_tasking.c:1131)
==21071==    by 0x4034FA: compute_x_ (omp_task_problem.f90:31)
==21071==    by 0x51DBCB2: __kmp_invoke_microtask (in /scratch/software/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libiomp5.so)
==21071==    by 0x51AA436: __kmp_invoke_task_func (kmp_runtime.c:7058)
==21071==    by 0x51AB60A: __kmp_fork_call (kmp_runtime.c:2397)
==21071==    by 0x5184517: __kmpc_fork_call (kmp_csupport.c:339)
==21071==    by 0x403353: compute_x_ (omp_task_problem.f90:24)
==21071==    by 0x402F4C: MAIN__ (omp_task_problem.f90:10)
==21071== 
==21071== 24,117,248 bytes in 23 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 23 of 26
==21071==    at 0x4C29BFD: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21071==    by 0x516A807: bget(kmp_info*, long) (kmp_alloc.c:741)
==21071==    by 0x516A52D: ___kmp_fast_allocate (kmp_alloc.c:2012)
==21071==    by 0x51CB5E0: __kmpc_omp_task_with_deps (kmp_taskdeps.cpp:452)
==21071==    by 0x403D54: compute_x_ (omp_task_problem.f90:43)
==21071==    by 0x51DBCB2: __kmp_invoke_microtask (in /scratch/software/intel-2016/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/libiomp5.so)
==21071==    by 0x51AA436: __kmp_invoke_task_func (kmp_runtime.c:7058)
==21071==    by 0x51AB60A: __kmp_fork_call (kmp_runtime.c:2397)
==21071==    by 0x5184517: __kmpc_fork_call (kmp_csupport.c:339)
==21071==    by 0x403353: compute_x_ (omp_task_problem.f90:24)
==21071==    by 0x402F4C: MAIN__ (omp_task_problem.f90:10)
==21071==    by 0x402E1D: main (in ./a.out)
...
```

The line numbers of the `compute_x_` function in the backtrace correspond to the `!$omp task` statements. These memory leaks accumulated rapidly to an amount of memory such that the program crashes. But changing the call of `COMPUTE_X` to

```
DO J = 1, 10000
   CALL COMPUTE_X(M,N, X, M) 
END DO
```

one can even use `top` to see that the memory requirements of the application explode.

Using gcc-6.2 for this `valgrind` ends up with:

```
==21246== LEAK SUMMARY:
==21246==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21246==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21246==      possibly lost: 8,640 bytes in 15 blocks
==21246==    still reachable: 4,624 bytes in 4 blocks
==21246==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21246==
```

where the leaks are only from the first initialization of the OpenMP runtime system.

So my question is: Why does the Intel Compiler/Intel OpenMP runtime system produce theses leaks or alternatively is there an error in the way I have 
designed the task parallelism.

Comment: In ifort one can compile with '-check bounds'. Would that help to verify that you are not overrunning memory? Or do you believe that you are allocating memory and not deal locating it?

Comment: Check bounds does not give any thing and it can easily be proven that there is not out-of-bound memory access in the code. The code it self does not allocate any dynamic memory. Only an array of size 256x256 is allocated by the compiler and not at runtime. The GNU compiler does not allocate any additional memory. But the Intel OpenMP rutime it self uses malloc's whenever the tasks are executed by the scheduler. And there seems to be the leak as valgrind points it out. The question is, is this leak a bug of the Intel Runtime or a missuse of OpenMP by myself.

Comment: If you suspect a bug in Intel software, you should really contact their Support Forums. Steve Lionel comes here regularly, but asking them directly is faster and there are more people there to help than just him.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. I posted it already in the support forums.. but I recognized that they are really slow in answering or even looking at the stuff. Interestingly the bug lasts inside the software at least since Parallel Studio XE 2015 Update 3. That was the oldest version which I had access to.

Comment: Note that the details you show from valgrind refer to 1MiB+24MiB while the leak summary refers to 118MiB on possibly lost memory. Does valgrind tell where are the remaining 118-1-24 = 93 MiB are allocated?

Comment: Harald... thats why I posted the three dots "..." there. In the sense of "to be continued" because the whole log is too long to be posted here and does not give any additional information.